# Istio: DestinationRule for a legacy service outside the mesh

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, mtls

I have a k8s cluster with Istio deployed in the `istio-system` namespace, and sidecar injection enabled by default in another namespace called `mesh-apps`. I also have a second `legacy` namespace which contains certain applications that do their own TLS termination. I am trying to setup mTLS access between services running inside the `mesh-apps` namespace and those running inside `legacy`.

For this purpose, I have done the following:

1. Created a secret in the `mesh-apps` namespace containing the client cert, key and CAcert to be used to connect with an application in legacy via mTLS.
2. Mounted these at a well-defined location inside a pod (the `sleep` pod in Istio samples actually) running in `mesh-apps`.
3. Deployed an app inside `legacy` and exposed it using a ClusterIP service called `mymtls-app` on port 8443.
4. Created the following destination rule in the `mesh-apps` namespace, hoping that this enables mTLS access from `mesh-apps` to `legacy`.

   ```
   ---
   apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
   kind: DestinationRule
   metadata:
     name: originate-mtls
   spec:
     host: mymtls-app.legacy.svc.cluster.local
     trafficPolicy:
       portLevelSettings:
       - port:
           number: 8443
         tls:
           mode: MUTUAL
           clientCertificate: /etc/sleep/tls/server.cert
           privateKey: /etc/sleep/tls/server.key
           caCertificates: /etc/sleep/tls/ca.pem
           sni: mymtls-app.legacy.svc.cluster.local
   ```

Now when I run the following command from inside the `sleep` pod, I would have expected the above `DestinationRule` to take effect:

```
kubectl exec sleep-37893-foobar -c sleep -- curl http://mymtls-app.legacy.svc.cluster.local:8443/hello
```

But instead I just get the error:

```
Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
```

If I add https in the URL, then this is the error:

```
curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate, errno 0
command terminated with exit code 56
```

Comment: its already taking effect that's where its complaining to include https in the url instead of http.  you should send request as curl https://mymtls-app.legacy.svc.cluster.local:8443/hello

Comment: That has the same effect. Not specifying anything would be same as specifying http?

Comment: Please include in url “https://“.

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal, that doesn't work either. I have updated the question with that detail. Shouldn't the DestinationRule help originate mTLS? Which requests would be intercepted?

Comment: You can pass “-k” option in curl

Comment: I have passed the -k option.

Comment: I found that the problem was the way I mounted the secrets.

Answer (score 2):

I figured my own mistake. I needed to correctly mount the certificate, private key, and CA chain in the sidecar, not in the app container. In order to mount them in the sidecar, I performed the following actions:

1. Created a secret with the cert, private key and CA chain.

   ```
   kubectl create secret generic sleep-secret -n mesh-apps \
     --from-file=server.key=/home/johndoe/certs_mtls/client.key \
     --from-file=server.cert=/home/johndoe/certs_mtls/client.crt \
     --from-file=ca.pem=/home/johndoe/certs_mtls/server_ca.pem
   ```
2. Modified the deployment manifest for the sleep container thus:

   ```
     template:
       metadata:
         annotations:
           sidecar.istio.io/userVolumeMount: '[{"name": "secret-volume", "mountPath": "/etc/sleep/tls", "readonly": true}]'
           sidecar.istio.io/userVolume: '[{"name": "secret-volume", "secret": {"secretName": "sleep-secret"}}]'
   ```

Actually I had already created the secret earlier, but it was mounted in the app container (`sleep`) instead of the sidecar, in this way:

```
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: <secret_volume_name>
    secret:
      secretName: <secret_name>
      optional: true
  containers:
  - name: ...
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: ...
      name: <secret_volume_name>
```