# mTLS between services running inside and outside a mesh using Istio's trust chain

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, mtls, spiffe

I understand that I can configure Istio for its Citadel component to use a root x509 certificate + private key that I provide. Can I extend this system in a way that I also use the same root to issue certificates to legacy workloads running in the same k8s cluster, and then configure a destination rule to access these workloads from inside the mesh? Something like:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: originate-mtls
spec:
  host: mymtls-app.legacy.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    portLevelSettings:
    - port:
        number: 8443
      tls:
        mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
        sni: mymtls-app.legacy.svc.cluster.local
```

Can the above work? Do I need any additional configuration besides the above? I may not be in a position to run spiffe / spire to manage the certificates for workloads outside the mesh - which puts a spiffe-federation solution [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cx_NnvbsCP4) somewhat out of reach for me. But this also doesn't seem like a fully supported mechanism in any case.

I have been able to configure mTLS using a separate certificate hierarchy which I have to inject via secrets and mount into the pods / sidecars in question (illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72833407/istio-destinationrule-for-a-legacy-service-outside-the-mesh)).

Comment: If you are using your own certificates then you need to use mode: MUTUAL and other attributes https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal, what does the DestinationRule documentation link add to the discussion? Could you point out which specific section or line is relevant to the question above?

Comment: If you want to use own certificate and private keys instead of citadel then you need to use mode: Mutual. The link has attributes which needs to be used.   If mode is ISTIO_MUTUAL it will automatically generates those.